# Can not add multiple conditions to where with left join and group

Tags: linq, entity-framework, group-by, entity-framework-6, left-join

Let's say I have this SQL:

```
SELECT p.ParentId, COUNT(c.ChildId)
FROM ParentTable p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ChildTable c ON p.ParentId = c.ChildParentId
where p.IsDeleted=0 and c.IsDeleted=0

GROUP BY p.ParentId
```

I tried to translate it to `Linq to Sql`, But I stuck with the problem which is can not adding more than 1 condition in the where clause.

```
from p in context.ParentTable
join c in context.ChildTable on p.ParentId equals c.ChildParentId into j1
where p.IsDeleted = false && c.IsDeleted=false
from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
group j2 by p.ParentId into grouped
select new { ParentId = grouped.Key, Count = grouped.Count(t=>t.ChildId != null) }
```

The error is `The name c does not exist in the current context.`

How can I solve this problem ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 from p in context.ParentTable.Where(x=>x.IsDeleted = false)
    join c in context.ChildTable.Where(y=>y.IsDeleted=false) on p.ParentId equals c.ChildParentId into j1
    from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group j2 by p.ParentId into grouped
    select new { ParentId = grouped.Key, Count = grouped.Count(t=>t.ChildId != null) }
```

Comment: No. I tried to move it into on clause. also doesn't work.